# Make a task depend on another task

Tags: groovy, gradle

I´m trying things in gradle, and I want to define a task called "jenkins" that depends on one module task called "test" and another module task called "connectedAndroidTest". I´m following the instructions on http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html

This is my output of "./gradlew tasks"

```
------------------------------------------------------------
All tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------
[..]
Verification tasks
------------------
[..]
connectedAndroidTest - Installs and runs the tests for Build 'debug' on connected devices.
test - Runs the unit tests.

Other tasks
-----------
wrapper
```

So I would assume, that this:

```
task jenkins
jenkins.dependsOn test
jenkins.dependsOn connectedAndroidTest
```

would create this task, and make it depend on the other ones, so my jenkins only needs to run

```
./gradlew jenkins
```

If I have other tasks to be added to the jenkins run, I only need to change the gradle file and I don´t have to touch the jenkins.

But instead I´m getting this nasty error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android-near-gradle'.
> Could not find property 'test' on root project 'android-near-gradle'.
```

also

```
task jenkins
jenkins.dependsOn unit:test
jenkins.dependsOn library:connectedAndroidTest
```

does lead to the same problem.

As sugested I tried this:

```
jenkins.dependsOn project(':unit').test
jenkins.dependsOn project(':library').connectedAndroidTest
```

which led to:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android-near-gradle'.
> Could not find property 'test' on project ':unit'.
```

Looking deeper into the documentation of the Gradle Objects I came up with this:

```
task jenkins
jenkins.dependsOn project(':unit').tasks.getByName('test')
jenkins.dependsOn project(':library').tasks.getByName('androidConnectedTest')
```

**But this led to this error. It might be a problem, because the modules may not have been loaded yet?!**

This is even more weird, because the error message is wrong

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android-near-gradle'.
> Task with name 'test' not found in project ':unit'.
```

When I execute

```
./gradlew :unit:test
```

The "test" task of the module "unit" is beeing executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of gradle you are on?

Comment: I´m using Gradle 1.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When declaring a task dependency like this:

```
task jenkins
jenkins.dependsOn test
jenkins.dependsOn connectedAndroidTest
```

you need to be sure that `test`and `connectedAndroidTest` tasks are already created. Since you're using the android plugin it is very likely that some tasks creations are deferred. On possible fix to that problem is to reference the tasks your jenkins task dependsOn by using the string notation. This way gradle should wire the correct tasks together no matter where in the build script (or plugins) they are declared:

```
task jenkins
jenkins.dependsOn "test"
jenkins.dependsOn "connectedAndroidTest"
jenkins.dependsOn ":unit:test"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jenkins.dependsOn ":unit:test"
jenkins.dependsOn "library:connectedAndroidTest"
```

actually works.

So referencing the tasks by string is the way to go because the other tasks are not known jet, since they are modules of the main gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jenkins.dependsOn project(':unit').test
```

Comment: Okay, I ended up putting my new findings in the question. Short: It doesn´t work :(

Comment: Any minimal working example accessible on e.g. GitHub to have a try? I might be the problem with project evaluation.